# django filter check conditions

Tags: django

here im using

```
age_from:-------    age to:--------------    //here ---- is text field
date from:------     dat_to:-------------

search button // this is my search button.
```

here i match the conditions if select age from it will search the age which is greater on the base on date (date from to date_to)
similarly for rest of the cases as mention in below code:

now my problem is :

```
gender : o male o female
age_from:-------    age to:--------------
date from:------     dat_to:-------------
```

now how can i write the condition for gender part ,age part and date part.. its bit confusing im getting exactly... help me..

```
def search(request):

    age_from = request.POST["age_from"]
    age_to = request.POST["age_to"]
    date_from = request.POST["date_from"]
    date_to = request.POST["date_to"] 


    if age_from:
        age1 = 1
    if age_to:
        age2 = 1
    if date_from:
        date1 = 1
    if date_to:
        date2 = 1


    if age1 and not age2:
        if date1 and date2:
            patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__gte=age_from , dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to))
        else:
            if date1:
                patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__gte=age_from,dateedit__gte=date_from)
            else:
                if date2:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__gte=age_from, dateedit__lte=date_to)
                else:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__gte=age_from)

    if age2 and not age1:
        if date1 and date2:
            patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__lte=age_to, dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to))
        else:
            if date1:
                patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__lte=age_to, dateedit__gte=date_from)
            else:
                if date2:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__lte=age_to, dateedit__lte=date_to)
                else:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__lte=age_to)

    if age1 and age2:
        if date1 and date2:
            patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__range=(age_from,age_to),dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to))
        else:
            if date1:
                patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__range=(age_from,age_to),dateedit__gte=date_from)
            else:
                if date2:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__range=(age_from,age_to),dateedit__lte=date_to)
                else:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(age__range=(age_from,age_to))


    if date1 and not date2:
        if age1 and age2:
            patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__gte=date_from, age1__range=(age_from,age_to))
        else:
            if age1:
                patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__gte=date_from, age__gte=age_from)
            else:
                if age2:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__gte=date_from, age__lte=age_to)
                else:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__gte=date_from)

    if date2 and not date1:
        if age1 and age2:
            patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__lte=date_to, age1__range=(age_from,age_to))
        else:
            if age1:
                patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__lte=date_to, age__gte=age_from)
            else:
                if age2:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__lte=date_to, age__lte=age_to)
                else:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__lte=date_to)

    if date1 and date2:
        if age1 and age2:
            patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to), age1__range=(age_from,age_to))
        else:
            if age1:
                patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to),age__gte=age_from)
            else:
                if age2:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to), age__lte=age_to)
                else:
                    patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to))
```

the above code is for age and date part... is working perfectly....
but when comes with three condition it confusing.. not getting

please write the code for gender,age and date part.. as above thanx in advance...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you add filter conditions as they are needed, and not try to fork your code like you do. Here is an example, how you can do it:

```
patient = PatientInfo.objects.all(); # getting all patients (don't worry, query is not executed yet)

if age_from:
    patient = patient.filter(age__gte=age_from)

if age_to:
    patient = patient.filter(dateedit__lte=date_to)

if gender:
    patient = patient.filter(gender=gender)

# ...and so on
```

Conditions will be added one to another and the actual query will be executed when you will try to refference the result. Isn't django cool?

Comment: im having confusion as what u think plz write the code for gender, age and date part... im new to django.. plz help....:(

Comment: @gur, I am not sure how you models look and how your fields are named, but I added the example. Hope you understand the idea.

Comment: class PatientInfo(models.Model):                                  gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)                                     age = models.IntegerField()                                    dateedit = models.DateTimeField()  here is my model and im nt getting for gender age and date part actually its bit confusing can u plz write the code.. n already i add my code as above.   plz help silver light

Comment: @gur, sorry, read the docs if you do not understand how queries work: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/