# django query not matching

Tags: django

my query is not working properly. when i select the male part and then age_from to age_to and date_from to date_to its  not actually select the male from my database according to my query .actually according to my database male record between age 5 to age 15 and date 2011-04-05 to 2011-05-05 is only 1 but it showing 3 records.

this is my query: as follows
patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to),age__range=(age_from,age_to),gender__iexact='male')

i think there is some wrong in my query.. im nt getting exactly...

flag = 0
    if request.POST.has_key('gender'):
        search_gender = request.POST["gender"]

```
    if search_gender == 'male':
        flag == 1

    if search_gender == 'female':
        flag == 2

    if search_gender == 'both':
        flag == 3

age_from = request.POST["age_from"]
age_to = request.POST["age_to"]
date_from = request.POST["date_from"]
date_to = request.POST["date_to"]
```

patient = PatientInfo()

```
if date1 and date2:
    if age1 and age2:
             if flag == 1:
                 patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to),age__range=(age_from,age_to),gender__iexact='male')
             else:
                  patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to),age__range=(age_from,age_to))
                  if flag == 2:
                      patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to),age__range=(age_from,age_to),gender__iexact='female')
                  else:
                      patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to),age__range=(age_from,age_to))
                      if flag == 3:
                          patient = PatientInfo.objects.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to),age__range=(age_from,age_to),gender__iexact='male')
```

Comment: Three pointers - 1 you can build up queries bit by bit, adding extra filters - 2 - use char or integer fields with a `choices` parameter for your gender. - 3 - use `elif` to tidy things up

Comment: turned the above comment into an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [django filter check conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787265/django-filter-check-conditions)

Comment: Yeah it's a pretty close match. I won't vote to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

You can build up queries bit by bit, adding extra filters as you go. This will tidy up your logic. Also, `elif` is your friend. Also, next time use `CHOICES` for values like gender.

I have not tested this, but this is the kind of syntax you want

```
query = PatientInfo.objects.all()

if date1 and date2:
    query = query.filter(dateedit__range=(date_from,date_to))

if flag == 1:
    query = query.filter(gender__iexact='male')
elif flag == 2:
    query = query.filter(gender__iexact='female')
```

Then use `query` as normal. Realise that queries objects are different to result sets. As you add things to your query, you are only changing a query expression tree that will be turned into SQL. Only when you execute it (turn it into a list, iterating etc) does it query the db and turn into a result set. So don't be scared to refactor logic to make tweaks to the query object.

Also be aware that you're comparing a string to an int. If you want to get the integer value, you want `thing = int(request.POST['thing'])`.

Comment: no the problem is in query showing the incorrect records .actually its only 1 record of male between date 2011-04-05 to 2011-05-05 and age between 5 to 15 its according to my database record when im running manually in mysql it showing correct record but according to as above my code is showing 3 i think there is some mistake in gender__iexact='male' i think it also select female plz help im not getting where im wrong... thanx in advance

Comment: Well, for a start, your logic is complicated and difficult to understand when a problem like this appears. Try replacing it with  code in this style and see if it works.

Comment: Also, you were getting strings from POST and comparing them to integers. `"1" != 1`.